# Spread or Rest operator clarification ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm following a react tutorial and I need a little clarification.  In the render function of the App.js component, the spread operator is used on the contest object exposed by mapping over the contests array.  How is the ContestPreview.js Component able to use it as props without the property being named and why is the spread operator being used in this instance?

Thanks.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import ContestPreview from './ContestPreview';
import data from '../testData';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageHeader: 'Naming Contests',
      contests: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      contests: data.contests
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Header message={this.state.pageHeader} />
        <div>
          {this.state.contests.map(contest =>
            <ContestPreview key={contest.id} {...contest}
             />
          )};
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ContestPreview.js

```
import React from 'react';

const ContestPreview = (contest) => (
  <div className='ContestPreview'>
    <div className='category-name'>
      {contest.categoryName}
    </div>
    <div className='contest-name'>
      {contest.contestName}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default ContestPreview;
```

Comment: It's a convenience method since you're spreading the properties of those objects. What do you mean by "rest" operator? Never heard of that

Comment: @ZekeDroid This example doesn't have a "rest" but that would be like `const [a, b, ...others] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];`

Comment: `...` is not an operator, it's a [*punctuator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-punctuators) and part of the [*rest*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-AssignmentRestElement) and [*spread*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-SpreadElement) syntaxes. Also see MDN [*Rest parameters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [*Spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Comment: `Spread` expands the variable, while the `rest` condenses into one variable.
`Spread` is usually used to copy one object to another, concat two arrays etc, while `rest` is used to capture variable arguments  in a function. The above mentioned `spread` is JSX specific one which expands an object properties.

Comment: [**Rest Parameters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) AND [**Spread Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)! Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of

```
<div {...props} />
```

the spread syntax (`...`) here is specifically JSX, it has its own JSX-defined behavior because it is not a normal ES6 spread, nor is it the proposed object spread.

[The JSX spread syntax](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) will take all of the properties of the given object, and pass them as part of `props` to the child component.